# How to add multiple Access privileges in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

currently i have Access privileges like below

```
postgres=# \l
                                             List of databases
         Name         |     Owner      | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |         Access privileges
----------------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+------------------------------------
 core_db              | postgres       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                      +
                      |                |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 core_db_20221228     | postgres       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                      +
                      |                |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres             +
                      |                |          |         |         | coredbuser=CTc/postgres
 postgres             | postgres       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
```

i want this kind of Access privileges

```
postgres=# \l
                                             List of databases
         Name         |     Owner      | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |         Access privileges
----------------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+------------------------------------
 core_db              | postgres       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                      +
                      |                |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres             +
                      |                |          |         |         | coredbuser=CTc/postgres
 core_db_20221228     | postgres       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                      +
                      |                |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres             +
                      |                |          |         |         | coredbuser=CTc/postgres
 postgres             | postgres       | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
```

How to add multiple Access privileges in Postgres

Comment: Do you know how to add them individually?

Answer (score 0):

As user postgres run the following:

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "core_db" to coredbuser;**

This will grant to user coredbuser the following privileges on database core_db:

- CREATE   C
- TEMPORARY T
- CONNECT c